# Getting Caliburn.micro to update a user control that wraps a winforms component

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am trying to have a winforms graph (System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization) in a WPF application with Caliburn.micro.

I have a user control which basically wraps the Chart and presents it in a control.
It looks like this:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WindowsFormsHost">
        <winformchart:Chart x:Name="WinformChart" Dock="Fill" MouseClick="ChartControl_MouseClick">
            <winformchart:Chart.Series>
                <winformchart:Series Name="series" ChartType="Line"/>
            </winformchart:Chart.Series>
            <winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
                <winformchart:ChartArea/>
            </winformchart:Chart.ChartAreas>
        </winformchart:Chart>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</DockPanel>
```

The control is used in a view that has a corresponding view model. I would like to have the view model update the chart.

This is how I wire up the chart to the view model:

```
_view = IoC.Get<MyView>();
Chart = _view.ChartControl1.WinformChart;
```

where `ChartControl1` is the XAML name of the chart in the view, and `Chart` is a property in the view model.

**1) Is this really a good idea of wiring up the user control to the view model?**

My view model updates the chart values (`Chart.Series[0].Points[i].SetValueXY(i, data[i])`) and then it invalidates `Chart` to update the user control.
However, nothing is displayed in the control.

**2) What could be wrong with this approach?**

**2.a) Does Caliburn.micro need some special instruction that it should update the user control?**

Comment: This seems like a violation of MVVM in that the ViewModel is referencing the view directly. Ideally you want to bind the chart to properties on the VM and if the chart needs a specific update, send the update notification using a loosely-coupled mechanism such as the event aggregator or some other mediator model. However, I'm not sure how well the winforms chart would support the bindings - but you could still send all of this notification data (including the series plotting) to the view via the event aggregator. Then the VM can be decoupled from the view.

Comment: I agree that it is violating the principle. I will implement your suggestion, however, I can't understand why it is not working as it is now, when there is a tight coupling.

Comment: I think that the violation of MVVM also has the result that you have 2 instances of MyView, one which is shown on the screen, but not bound to your viewmodel, and one which is not shown on the screen but  bound to your viewmodel. Check how many times the constructor of MyView is called.